# Add Navigation Bar on ChildViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar, childviewcontroller

I want a new View Controller as a pop-up (which have some Parents View Controller scene ). So i am decided to add childViewController (which have 50px transparent border from all side.) Now when i adding childViewController i didn't get navigationBar. This is how i am adding full sized childViewController.

```
    ShowPostTVC *postvcObj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowPostTVC"];

    UINavigationController *childNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:postvcObj];
  [self.navigationController addChildViewController:childNavController];
  [self.navigationController.view addSubview:postvcObj.view];
  [postvcObj didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

How i can i get real navigation Bar on childViewController.

Comment: does it work now? any other issues? :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of showing a new ViewController is via UINavigationController's pushViewController:animated. Then the new ViewController has a NavigationBar:

```
ShowPostTVC *postvcObj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowPostTVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:postvcObj animated:true];
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of instantiating a new `UINavigationController` just use the following:

```
ShowPostTVC *postvcObj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowPostTVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:postvcObj];
```